# Widget configuration activity doesn't start

Tags: java, android, widget

As I understood, if I define configuration activity for widget, onUpdate() method will not call, until I'll not configure it. But in my case, and I wonder why - configuration activity doesn't start, and update method calls after placing widget. My application have other activities, one of them starts when application run, maybe that's is the reason? Here my code:

### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.watcom.MobileInformer"
          android:versionCode="2"
          android:versionName="1.01"
        >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="8"/>
    <application  android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/WatcomTheme" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
        <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
                          android:normalScreens="true"
                          android:largeScreens="true"
                          android:xlargeScreens="false"/>
        <activity android:name=".AuthorizationActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                <action android:name="com.watcom.MobileInformer.UPDATE_WIDGET"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name=".WidgetConfigureActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ProjectsActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

        <receiver
                android:icon="@drawable/icon"
                android:label="Watcom informer"
                android:name=".MyWidgetProvider" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            <action android:name="ru.example.android.widget.ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.watcom.MobileInformer.UPDATE_WIDGET"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                    android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                    android:resource="@xml/widget_provider" />
        </receiver>
    </application>

    <uses-permission xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                     android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

### widget_provider.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:minHeight="320dp"
                    android:minWidth="100dp"
                    android:updatePeriodMillis="1800000"
                    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_layout"
                    android:configuration="com.watcom.MobileInformer.WidgetConfigureActivity"/>
```

### WidgetConfigureActivity

```
public class WidgetConfigureActivity extends Activity {
    int widgetId;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_layout);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras!=null)
            widgetId = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                    AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
        if (widgetId == AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) {
            finish();
        }

        Intent resultValue = new Intent();
        resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, widgetId);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue);
        finish();
    }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please clarify what is your issue ?

Comment: As I understood, if I will reference to configuration activity in widget proveder, onUpdate() method will not call, untill widget will not be configured. And activity must starts automatically after placing widget to homescreen. But in my case, onUpdate() calls right after placing widget, and activity doesn't start. Where am I wrong?

Comment: OnUpdate method will be called each and everytime as many times widget will be updated.